# AS3 Game - Jump Doesn't Alter Velocity

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having problems making my Player jump in AS3. I'll upload everything relevant, I'm really struggling to figure out exactly what I've done wrong. It used to work but now it doesn't, I spent so long fixing errors I can't figure out where this messed up.  The Player Class is extended from the BoundaryObject class. I know the function is activated because the Player's `this.gotoAndStop("jump");` works.

> Player Class - Function for Jump

```
public function startJumping():void
{
    if (isJumping == false)
    {

        isJumping = true;
        this.gotoAndStop("jump");
        downwardVelocity = -28;
    }
}
```

> BoundaryObject Class - Variables/Loop for gravity

```
public var downwardVelocity:Number;
protected var isRunning:Boolean;
public var isJumping:Boolean;

public function BoundaryObject()
{

    trace("i am any object that collides with the boundary");

    downwardVelocity = 0;
    isRunning = false;

    this.gotoAndStop("jump");

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);

    // constructor code
}

private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{

    downwardVelocity +=  2; //equals itself plus 2
    this.y += downwardVelocity;

}

public function incrementUpward()
{
    //increment the y up until not colliding
    this.y -= 0.1;

}

public function keepOnBoundary()
{
    downwardVelocity = 0;//stops pulling the object down

}
```

Comment: Where do you call startJumping? Where do you call incrementUpward? When would you set back isJumping to false?

Comment: Most likely you mistake `BoundaryObject.downwardVelocity` with `Player.downwardVelocity`, altering the former in BO and the latter in `jump()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just at first glance, maybe set your jump boolean to `true` as you are setting this frame in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the downwardVelocity of the parent.

```
parent.downwardVelocity = -28;
```